# Open excel with specific filename and path via Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a 2 excel file in the same path. For the first excel, I give a input for users. When they enter year-month-day, its happening 20210830(example). As you see below, I merge user's input and fixed "dh" and fixed "path". İf this path include this folder names, file will open.

My r**eal question is about "Second Excel".
what i want is when the user enters the date for the first excel, it will search the file by combining the name of the second excel in the same file path and one business day before that date**

```
#first_excel = dh20210830
#second_excel = Test_Value_Serie_After_20210827_123456
path = K:\Test\
suffix = dh
final = path + dh + date
data = pd.read_csv(final,sep=';',encoding='utf-8')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
add_year = str(input("Year:"))
add_month = str(input("Month:"))
add_day = str(input("Day:"))
date = add_year + add_month + add_day
suffix_second = Test_Value_Serie_After_
final_second = suffix_second + """""one business day before the user enters""""" + _123456 (But this number can be variable. So don't rely on these numbers. If there are different numbers, it may be in that file.)
```

```
constant variables = Test_Value_Serie_After_
path = K:\Test\
variable things = date(users input) and _123456(this number can be any number)
```

Note: As I told you, after last "_", open the file regardless of the numbers after it.

expected output:

```
suffix_second = Test_Value_Serie_After_
date_second = date - 1 business day (in this example 20210827)...2 day is weekend)
final_second = suffix_second + date_second + '_'(open the file regardless of the numbers after it)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay` or use a custom business day if you have for example specific holidays off, etc.

```
add_year = str(input("Year:"))
add_month = str(input("Month:"))
add_day = str(input("Day:"))
date = add_year + add_month + add_day
# convert date to datetime then offset 1 business day
date_offset = pd.to_datetime(date) - pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay(1) 

print(date_offset)

Year: 2021
Month: 08
Day: 30
2021-08-27 00:00:00
```

Then you can convert the date back to a string

```
str_date_offset = str(date_offset.date()).replace('-', '') # -> '20210827'
```

user `glob` to match the pattern of the file name

```
import glob

file_name = glob.glob(f'{suffix_second}{str_date_offset}_*.csv')[0]
print(file_name)
```

Comment: suffix_second = Test_Value_Serie_After_ + str_date_offset + _123456(how can I make this? after last "_", open the file regardless of the numbers after it. For example, _123456 may not be 123456, it can be 6789 or 23 etc.

Comment: @Bianconera use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to pattern-match the file name.

Comment: I dont know the glob module. Can you help me?.  You made date part. open the file regardless of the numbers after "_" .

Comment: Try something like `file_name = glob.glob(f'{str_date_offset}_*.csv')[0]` Assuming the second file is a csv. This will match all files that start with `20210827_` and end with `any text` and `.csv`

Comment: ParserError: year 2021830 is out of range: 2021830 . I think when you enter month like "8" its not happening

Comment: @Bianconera you need to parse the date in the proper format (e.g., YYYYMMDD) or specify the format in `pd.to_datetime`